# javascript anonymous params vs variable

Tags: javascript, parameters

i am trying to use the google drive list api 
and it needs some parameters

this works passing parms in anonymous structure

```
service.files.list({
    'auth': auth,
    'pageSize': 1,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,parents)",
    'pageToken': nextPageToken
  }, function(err, response) {}
```

where this fails (with some sort of invalid authorization)

```
var params={
    'auth': auth,
    'pageSize': 1,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,parents)",
    'pageToken': nextPageToken
  }
service.files.list(params, function(err, response) {}
```

I don't understand the distinction between the two

Comment: neither should work as they both have syntax errors.

Add a closing curly bracket after both. You also want to have a semi-colon after your params variable declaration in the second one

Comment: thanks.. its only the value of the 1st param i am interested in.. this is not a syntactically correct snippet

Answer (score 0):

I've got an inkling it's something to do with the variable name `params`. try changing it to something else e.g. `gdParams`. You may have inadvertently used `params` elsewhere.

```
var gdParams = {
  'auth': auth,
  'pageSize': 1,
  'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink, parents)",
  'pageToken': nextPageToken,
};

service.files.list(gdParams, function(err, response) {});
```

Answer (score -1):

As George suggested above:

```
 var params={
    'auth': auth,
    'pageSize': 1,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,parents)",
    'pageToken': nextPageToken
 };
service.files.list(params, function(err, response) {});
```

And:

```
service.files.list({
    'auth': auth,
    'pageSize': 1,
    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,webViewLink,parents)",
    'pageToken': nextPageToken
}, function(err, response) {});
```

(you were missing some closing parentheses and semicolons)

See if that helps?
Cheers!

Comment: thanks.. those were cut and paste errors.. not the actual source of the problem

Comment: this works..`params={}; params.auth=auth.....   this does not parms={auth:auth...}`

Comment: Maybe it's another cut and paste error, but it says `parms` in your comment. Did you mean `params`?